# Как добавить пару папок в url?

Tags: url, .htaccess

Был произведен перенос сайта на другой хостинг. На новом хостинге сайт существует в папке `/rent/perl/`. В .htaccess прописал путь к новому индексномук файлу, сайт стартанул. Но все файлы стилей, картинки и прочее не подхватывается. Страница открывается просто с текстом и с покоцанными картинками.

Как сделать так, чтобы, к примеру, в ссылке `http://site.ru/assets/` между доменом и всеми последующими кусками url вставить `/rent/perl/`, чтобы в итоге было `http://site.ru/rent/perl/assets/`?

Пробовал так, не помогло:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /rent/perl/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @CraftLawrence, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

?

```
RewriteRule ^assets/? rent/perl/assets/ [L]
```